# Aggregate Query by Matching The Same field for Multiple Id Values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a booking schema where booking is done by multiple clients.

```
    var booking = new Schema({
     booking: {

         start_time : { type: Date },
         end_time :  { type: Date },
         park_location_id: {  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId },
         clientId:  {  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId },
  }
});
```

Here I am looking for a way in which i can pass multiple clientIds in an array and perform aggregation for all of them and get the aggregated result in one single query.Right now I am performing a loop operation to fetch result of each client.

```
    booking.statics.totalCheckinReport = function(id,callback){ 
   // Here id is single client
   // can I pass an array of clientID as [ id1, id2,id3]
   // and get the aggregated result of all of them
        this.aggregate([
            {
                $match:
                    {
                        $and:[
                            {'booking.park_location_id' : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)}
                        ]
                    }
            },
            {
                $group :{
                    _id : id,
                    totalCheckinCount: { $sum : 1 },
                }
            }
            ]).exec(function(err, data){
              if(err)
                 callback(null,err);
              else
                callback(null, data);
         })
    }
```

So is there a better way to do this without looping through clientsID and passing it to my mongoose function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically just apply [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) for the list of values and actually use the "field value" rather than a "static value" for the grouping `_id`. Because writing `"$group": { "_id": id` may as well be `"$group": { "_id": null`. You get more utility out of using the "field value" instead:

```
    booking.statics.totalCheckinReport = function(ids,callback){
        // using ids as an array as input
        ids = ids.map( id => mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) ); // Cast each array member
        this.aggregate([
          { $match:{
            'booking.park_location_id' : { $in: ids }
          }},
          { $group :{
            _id : '$booking.park_location_id'  // <-- Actually use the field value
            totalCheckinCount: { $sum : 1 },
          }}
        ]).exec(callback)                     // <-- this already passes the error
                                              // and result
    }
```

Calling as

```
Booking.totalCheckinReport([id1,id2,id3],function(err,result) {
  // deal with response here
});
```

Also note that an explicit `$and` ( even when you actually did have more than one argument ) is almost never actually required. All arguments are actually already "AND" conditions, and as long as the conditions are specified for "separate keys" then there is no need for the "array form" argument.